# How do I find the voltage source?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, inductor, impedance

I need help with this question.  The purpose of this question is to find V<sub>s</sub>. The current given is I<sub>o</sub> which I use as I<sub>3</sub>.

However,the result I get is different from the answer. Can anyone help me check my work or tell me what the correct method is I should use? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I'm not going to try and read that.

Answer (score 1):

The photo is difficult to read. I cannot see reliably where is j and where is 3. The approach to build the voltage sum equations and to eliminate everything but Vs is theoretically perfect. There's an error somewhere and I cannot read the mess reliably enough to see where.

A practical electrician avoids mangling equation groups. He would calculate the total complex impedance  of

1. the parts to the left from Vs and
2. the parts to the right from Vs.

In addition he would calculate the total complex voltage over the series of 1 ohm resistor and the -j Ohm capacitor.

=> the complex current through the inductor in the right side of Vs => the total complex current in the bottom wire between the halves => The complex voltage over the left side complex impedance => Vs.

Comment: Sorry for the untidiness. Will try to write a better version next time. Thanks for the help:)